# dart-define not working when running a standalone Dart program

Tags: dart

I have a single file Dart program - let's say `main.dart`. I'm trying to provide some compile time environment values to it using `--dart-define=env=env_value` but in the Dart program, I'm always getting the default values.

This is what my Dart program looks like

```
void main() {
  const myValue = const String.fromEnvironment("MY_VALUE", defaultValue: "DEFAULT");
  print('My value: $myValue'); // Always prints "DEFAULT"

}
```

This is the command I'm using to run my program

```
dart main.dart --dart-define=MY_VALUE=SOME_VALUE
```

Now, when I include the exact same code from above in a Flutter app and run it with the below command, everything seems to work as expecetd but for some reason the above program always prints `DEFAULT` as the output on console.

```
flutter run --dart-define=MY_VALUE=SOME_VALUE
```

Is there something I'm missing when it comes to providing these values in a Dart program? I'm running macOS if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type:

```
dart --help --verbose
```

It will give you the list of supported flags.

```
Usage: dart [<vm-flags>] <dart-script-file> [<script-arguments>]

Executes the Dart script <dart-script-file> with the given list of <script-arguments>.

Supported options:
...
--define=<key>=<value> or -D<key>=<value>
  Define an environment declaration. To specify multiple declarations,
  use multiple instances of this option.
...
```

So it appears that the flag you want is `--define` or `-D`, rather than `--dart-define`. Also note that this is considered a "vm-flag" and must come before the file name in order to work.

Therefore the following command should work:

```
dart --define=MY_VALUE=SOME_VALUE main.dart
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. One small addition though, the program still works if I add the flag after the file name.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh it prints out "DEFAULT" on my machine if the flag is placed after the file name, and "SOME_VALUE" if it is placed before.

Comment: That's weird. I'm on SDK version 2.18.5 stable and running on macOS.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh I am also on 2.18.5 but am testing on windows 10. Maybe that would explain a difference in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When passing **arguments in key-value pairs** from the command line, you need to follow this syntax.

`dart --define=MY_KEY=SOME_VALUE main.dart`

In order to pass multiple key-value pairs:

`dart --define=MY_KEY=SOME_VALUE --define=MY_ANOTHER_KEY=SOME_OTHER_VALUE main.dart`