# How to pass --dart-define variables to `dart test`?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

I want to pass variables to tests run in pure Dart the same way as one can pass them in Flutter.

Flutter example:

```bash
$ flutter test --dart-define=FOO=BAR
```

```
  test('Value is correct', () {
    expect(const String.fromEnvironment('FOO'), 'BAR'); // passes
  });
```

Dart example:

```bash
$ dart test --dart-define=FOO=BAR

Could not find an option named "dart-define".
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75002440/dart-define-not-working-when-running-a-standalone-dart-program) helps you?

Comment: The `dart` binary is separate from the `flutter` binary; they have different command-line options. `dart` does not have a `--dart-define=KEY=VALUE` command-line option (that naming would be redundant); it's just `dart --define=KEY=VALUE`.  However, it does not seem to work with `dart test`, which is a bug: https://github.com/dart-lang/test/issues/1794

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks, you solved it. I added an answer below, but if you want to add yours feel free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of `flutter test --dart-define=FOO=BAR` seems to be `dart --define=FOO=BAR test` or `dart -DFOO=BAR test`. Notice that `test` is written after the `--define` flag in the Dart command.

As of writing the comment the `--define` flag still won't work when used as shown in the examples above. For it to work we need to add `--use-data-isolate-strategy` to the end of the command. This seems to be a bug in Dart, as shown in [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/test/issues/1794#issuecomment-1322721423).

In the end this would be the working equivalent:

- `dart --define=FOO=BAR test --use-data-isolate-strategy`
- `dart -DFOO=BAR test --use-data-isolate-strategy`